# c++ putting 3 different objects into one vector

Tags: c++, object, dynamic, vector

i'm still kinda new to C++ and first i would like to apologize for the long spam of codes.

I'm actually using polyphormism for calculating the area of the square and other shapes
so how do I actually make use of dynamically create an object this way? such that I could actually store all 3 different shapes in one vector so that i'm able to do a sort after this. I'm also not sure if i'm doing this right..

please kindly advice.

Shape2DLink.h

```
    #ifndef Shape2DLink_H
#define Shape2DLink_H

#include "ShapeTwoD.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Shape2DLink:public ShapeTwoD
{
    public:
        int getx();
        int gety();

        double getArea();

        void InputSensor();//allow user to input data
        void StoreData();
        vector<unique_ptr<ShapeTwoD>> objs;
};
#endif
```

Shape2DLink.cpp

```
   ShapeTwoD shape2D;
Square square;
Rectangle rect;
Cross cross;
Shape2DLink shape2dlink;

void Shape2DLink::InputSensor()
{
    string shape,type;  

    cout<<endl<<"\n"<<"[ Input sensor data ]"<<endl;


    cout << "Please enter name of shape: " << endl;
        cin >> shape;
        shape2D.setName(shape); 

    cout << "Please enter special type : " << endl;
        cin >> type;
        shape2D.setWarpSpace(type);

    if(shape == "Square")
    {
        square.setSquareCord();
        square.computeArea();
        objs.push_back(new Square(square));
    }
    else if(shape =="Rectangle")
    {
        rect.setRectCord();
        rect.computeArea();
        objs.push_back(new Rectangle(rectangle));
    }
    else if(shape == "Cross")
    {
        cross.setCrossCord();
        cross.computeArea();
        objs.push_back(new Cross(cross));
    }
}
```

ShapeTwoD.h (parent class)

```
class ShapeTwoD
{
    public:
        string name, warpSpace;
        bool containsWarpSpace;
        int xCord, yCord;

        int xVal, yVal;
        int length, breath;
        double area;
    //public:
        //constructor
        ShapeTwoD();
        ShapeTwoD(string, bool);

        //accessors/set function
        void setName(string);
        void setValues(int, int);
        bool setContainsWarpSpace();
        void setWarpSpace(string);

        //mutator/get function
        string getName();
        bool getContainsWarpSpace();
        string getWarpSpace(); //get value of warpspace

        //methods
        string toString();
        virtual double computeArea();
        bool isPointInShape(int x, int y);
        bool isPointOnShape(int x, int y); 

        int xvalue[4];
        int yvalue[4];
};
```

ShapeTwoD.cpp

```
    using namespace std;

ShapeTwoD::ShapeTwoD()
{
    string name = "";
    bool containsWarpSpace = true;
}

ShapeTwoD::ShapeTwoD(string ShapeName, bool warpspace)
{
    name = ShapeName;
    containsWarpSpace = true;
}

void ShapeTwoD::setName(string shapeName)
{
    name=shapeName;
}

string ShapeTwoD::getName()
{
    return name;
}

string ShapeTwoD::toString()
{
    string s;
    return s;
}

void ShapeTwoD::setValues(int a, int b)
{
    length = a;
    breath = b;
}


bool ShapeTwoD::setContainsWarpSpace()
{
    string warp;
    if(warp=="WS")
    containsWarpSpace=true;
    else if(warp=="NS")
    containsWarpSpace=false;    
}


bool ShapeTwoD::getContainsWarpSpace()
{
   return containsWarpSpace;
}

void ShapeTwoD::setWarpSpace(string space)
{
    warpSpace=space;
}

string ShapeTwoD::getWarpSpace()
{
    return warpSpace;
}


double ShapeTwoD::computeArea()
{

    return area=0.00;
}
bool ShapeTwoD::isPointInShape(int x,int y)
{
    xCord = x;
    yCord = y;

    if(xCord > 5 || yCord > 5)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

bool ShapeTwoD::isPointOnShape(int x,int y)
{
    xCord = x;
    yCord = y;

   if(xCord > 10 || yCord <10)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

square.cpp

```
Square::Square()
{
    xVal = 0;
    yVal = 0;
}

Square::Square(string ShapeName, bool warpspace, int xval, int yval):ShapeTwoD(ShapeName, warpspace), xVal(xval), yVal(yval)
{
    xVal = xval;
    yVal = yval;
}

void Square::setSquareCord()
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter x-ordinate of pt " << i+1 << ": "; 
        cin >> xVal;
        xvalue[i] = xVal;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter y-ordinate of pt " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> yVal;
        yvalue[i] = yVal;
        cout << endl;
    }
}


double Square::computeArea()
{
    int xmax = xvalue[1];
    int xmin = xvalue[1];

    int ymax = yvalue[1];
    int ymin = yvalue[1];

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(xvalue[i]>xmax)
        {
            xmax = xvalue[i];
        }
        else if(xvalue[i]<xmin)
        {
            xmin = xvalue[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(yvalue[i]>ymax)
        {
            ymax = yvalue[i];
        }
        else if(yvalue[i]<ymin)
        {
            ymin = yvalue[i];
        }
    }
    length = xmax - xmin;
    breath = ymax - ymin;

    area = length * breath;

    return (area);
}
```

rect.h

```
class Rectangle:public ShapeTwoD
{
    private:
        int xVal,yVal;
        int length, breath;
        double area;

    public:
        Rectangle();
        Rectangle(string, bool, int, int);

        //mutator method
        //void setRectDetails(int x, int y);
        void setRectCord();

        //acessor method
        //int getRectDetails();
        int getxCord();
        int getyCord();

        bool isPointInShape(int x, int y);
        bool isPointOnShape(int x, int y);

        string toString();
        double computeArea();

        int xvalue[4];
        int yvalue[4];
};
```

rect.cpp

```
Rectangle::Rectangle()
{
    xVal = 0;
    yVal = 0;
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(string ShapeName, bool warpspace, int xval, int yval):ShapeTwoD(ShapeName, warpspace), xVal(xval), yVal(yval)
{
    xVal = xval;
    yVal = yval;
}

void Rectangle::setRectCord()
{
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter x-ordinate of pt " << i+1 << ": "; 
        cin >> xVal;
        xvalue[i] = xVal;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter y-ordinate of pt " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> yVal;
        yvalue[i] = yVal;
        cout << endl;
    }
}


double Rectangle::computeArea()
{
    int xmax = xvalue[1];
    int xmin = xvalue[1];

    int ymax = yvalue[1];
    int ymin = yvalue[1];

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(xvalue[i]>xmax)
        {
            xmax = xvalue[i];
        }
        else if(xvalue[i]<xmin)
        {
            xmin = xvalue[i];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(yvalue[i]>ymax)
        {
            ymax = yvalue[i];
        }
        else if(yvalue[i]<ymin)
        {
            ymin = yvalue[i];
        }
    }
    length = xmax - xmin;
    breath = ymax - ymin;

    area = length * breath;

    return (area);
}

int Rectangle::getxCord()
{
    return xVal;
}

int Rectangle::getyCord()
{
    return yVal;
}

string Rectangle::toString()
{
  string s;

  int xord = getxCord();
  int yord = getyCord();

  stringstream convertX;
  convertX << xord;

  stringstream convertY;
  convertY << yord;

  string xResult = convertX.str();
  string yResult = convertY.str();

  s += "Coordinate is: " + xResult + "";
  s += "," + yResult + "\n";

  return s;
}

bool Rectangle::isPointOnShape(int x,int y)
{
    x = getxCord();
    y = getyCord();

    if(x > 3 || y > 3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

bool Rectangle::isPointInShape(int x,int y)
{
    x = getxCord();
    y = getyCord();

    if(x > 5|| y >5)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

cross.h

```
    class Cross:public ShapeTwoD
    {
        private:
            int xVal,yVal;
            int length, breath;
            double area;

        public:
            Cross();
            Cross(string, bool, int, int);

            //mutator method
            //void setSquareDetails(int x, int y);
            void setCrossCord();

            //acessor method
            //int getSquareDetails();
            int getxCord();
            int getyCord();

            bool isPointInShape(int x, int y);
            bool isPointOnShape(int x, int y);

            string toString();
            double computeArea();

            int xvalue[12];
            int yvalue[12];


    };

cross.cpp

Cross::Cross()
{
    xVal = 0;
    yVal = 0;
}

Cross::Cross(string ShapeName, bool warpspace, int xval, int yval):ShapeTwoD(ShapeName, warpspace), xVal(xval), yVal(yval)
{
    xVal = xval;
    yVal = yval;
}

void Cross::setCrossCord()
{
    for (int j=0; j<12; j++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter x-ordinate of pt " << j+1 << ": "; 
        cin >> xVal;
        xvalue[j] = xVal;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter y-ordinate of pt " << j+1 << ": ";
        cin >> yVal;
        yvalue[j] = yVal;
        cout << endl;
    }
}


double Cross::computeArea()
{
    int points = 12;
    int running_total =0;
    int i;
    running_total = 0;
    for (i=0; i<points-1; i++)
    {
      running_total += xvalue[i]*yvalue[i+1] - xvalue[i+1]*yvalue[i]; //cross calculation of coord in a cross 
    }                                                                 //(x1*y2)-(y1*x1)

    running_total += xvalue[points-1]*yvalue[0] - xvalue[0]*yvalue[points-1];   // traverse back to the origin point (xn*y1)-(yn*x1)
    area = abs(running_total / 2); //purpose of absolute is to make sure result is positive. 
                                  //polygon are specified in counter-clockwise order (i.e. by the right-hand rule), then the area will be positive.
    //cout << area;
    return (area);
}

int Cross::getxCord()
{
    return xVal;
}

int Cross::getyCord()
{
    return yVal;
}

string Cross::toString()
{
  string s;

  int xord = getxCord();
  int yord = getyCord();

  stringstream convertX;
  convertX << xord;

  stringstream convertY;
  convertY << yord;

  string xResult = convertX.str();
  string yResult = convertY.str();

  s += "Coordinate is: " + xResult + "";
  s += "," + yResult + "\n";

  return s;
}

bool Cross::isPointOnShape(int x,int y)
{
    x = getxCord();
    y = getyCord();

    if(x > 3 || y > 3)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

bool Cross::isPointInShape(int x,int y)
{
    x = getxCord();
    y = getyCord();

    if(x > 5|| y >5)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: May be you can describe your issue/idea with a **short** code example?

Comment: Vector needs a Type and your ShapeTwoD is the super class for all you other objects, so you should be fine. I am still not clear on your question thu?

Comment: have you tried using a `std::vector<ShapeTwoD*>` ?

Comment: @unholysheep hi all i've actually updated the error msg i'm getting.. i'm not sure if what i've done so far allow me to store all different shape into a vector..

Comment: What do you intend with this line `objs.push_back(new Cross(*cross));` ?

Comment: I assume that `square` is a pointer to an object of class `Square` but why are you trying to call a constructor that you have not defined? (You only have defined two constructors and neither of them takes a pointer to a `Square` object)

Comment: @UnholySheep If `square` is a `Square`, then `*square` is not a poiner.

Comment: Your code is obscure: `square`, `cross`, and `rect` are not defined in `Shape2DLink::InputSensor()`

Comment: @UnholySheep so instead of objs.push_back(new Cross(*cross)); can i do it this way? 

objs.push_back(new Rectangle(rect[0]));

Comment: `unique_ptr` is your friend.  Try `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ShapeTwoD>>` and then `objs.emplace_back(new Rectangle(whatever))`

Comment: @UnholySheep so lets say for my square constructor it should consist of all the 4 set of coordinate as well?

Comment: After what @Walter pointed out, I am even more confused (obviously he is correct) - I do not know what your `rect` is but you still appear to try to call a constructor you have not defined. please post the definitions of `rect` `square` and `cross`

Comment: @UnholySheep this is what i've done so far.. inclusive of cross and rect.. i'm not sure what else am i missing..

Comment: please refer to @BenVoigt 's Answer, his code is how you should usually handle things like that. I would however advice you to read some good tutorials and books about classes and objects in C++, as your code suggests that you have not yet grasped the basics. It will definitely help you accomplish more complex tasks if you have a good understanding of OOP in C++

Comment: @UnholySheep c++ is my first programming language which i'm learning now.. though i still don't really uds, cos I sux at pointers but still greatly appreciate all the those help..

thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should help:

```
if(shape == "Square")
{
    Square* new_square;
    objs.emplace_back(new_square = new Square());
    new_square->setSquareCoord();
    new_square->computeArea();
}
```

and then change

```
vector<ShapeTwoD*> objs;
```

to

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<ShapeTwoD>> objs;
```

so that the objects will get properly deleted when their pointers are removed from the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many issues, most of which are obscured to us by your failure to provide variable definitions etc. However, it seems that `square` (in the body of `Shape2DLink::InputSensor()`) is an object, presumably of type `Square`, though it remains mysterious where it is defined (it's not an automatic variable nor a member of `Shape2DLink`). Unless you have defined it explicitly, `*square` makes not sense and the compiler reports an error. If `square` was a pointer, then `*square` would be (a reference to) the object pointed to.

I think you want to add a shape to your `objs`. This can be done via

```
objs.push_back(new Square);                 // calls default constructor for Square
objs.push_back(new Square(other_square));   // calls copy constructor
objs.push_back(new Square(parameters));     // calls some other constructor
```

In proper code, you would

**1** have the constructors of `Square` set all member data to appropriate values. Also, if you consider a `Square` to keep these values for its entire lifetime, you should make them `public const` members.

**2** use `std::unique_ptr<ShapeTwoD>` or `std::shared_ptr<ShapeTwoD>` to manage your objects' lifetime, look up their [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).